# Совместимость SQL SERVER старше 2008 c Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

Возможно ли совместить SQL server старше 2008 c Visual Studio 2010?
И можно ли в VS2010 работать с ASP.net MVC4 и EF5?

Answer (score 1):

Давайте обо всём по порядку.

> Возможно ли совместить SQL server старше 2008 c Visual Studio 2010?

Смотря для каких целей это делается...
Если требуется просто подключить БД через ADO.NET чтобы выполнять SQL запросы к таблицам и т.д., то по идее проблем возникнуть не должно.
В крайнем случае, можно попробовать установить SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT). Но, насколько мне известно:

1. SSDT для Visual Studio 2010 последний раз обновлялось в декабре 2012 года ([пруф](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj650014.aspx)).
2. Вышеупомянутое ПО уже недоступно для загрузки на официальном сайте (пруф приведён выше). Поэтому, где Вы его будете искать в случае надобности, я, если честно, даже не представляю.

> И можно ли в VS2010 работать с ASP.net MVC4 и EF5?

Судя по информации с [официальной страницы](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683), MVC4 может работать с .NET 4.0, но требует Visual Studio 2010 с установленным SP1.
EF5, согласно [официальной информации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj574253.aspx), также можно использовать в Visual Studio 2010, но в режиме ограниченной функциональности. Полностью все возможности будут доступны только в .NET 4.5, который Visual Studio 2010 не поддерживает.

Подводя итог можно сказать, что ответы на оба Ваших вопроса могут быть  положительными только с рядом оговорок.
Вообще Visual Studio 2010 на сегодняшний день уже очень сильно устарела. Поэтому, **если есть возможность** лучше возьмите версию по новее (хотя бы 2013).